# Comparing nested dictionary values within a list against eachother via loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, logic

I've got a program that scrape some stats and calculates the ELO of some teams over a basketball season. The problem persists when I'm trying to compute the expected win % of each team, but the values are all stored in the same nested dictionary list: `eList=[{'Perth': 1715}, {'Melbourne': 1683}, {'Phoenix': 1648}, {'Sydney': 1605}, {'The Hawks': 1573}, {'Brisbane': 1573}, {'Adelaide': 1523}, {'New Zealand': 1520}, {'Cairns': 1477}]`. I've tried nested for loops to iterate over two of the values at once , but it results in a error. I'm trying to iterate over all the ELO values of the various teams within the list-dictionary and then cross-compare them against each other so there values can be entered into my other function and the results output:

```
def expected_result(rating1, rating2):
    exp = (rating2 - rating1)/400.
    Ea = 1/(1 + math.pow(10, exp))
    Eb = 1/(1 + math.pow(10, -exp))
    return Ea*100, Eb*100
```

Comment: What is ELO value here ? for Perth ELO value is 1715 ?

Comment: Yep for Perth it's 1715, and for each other team its the number value in the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
eList=[{'Perth': 1715}, {'Melbourne': 1683}, {'Phoenix': 1648}, {'Sydney': 1605}, {'The Hawks': 1573}, {'Brisbane': 1573}, {'Adelaide': 1523}, {'New Zealand': 1520}, {'Cairns': 1477}]
val=[list(i.values())[0] for  i in eList]
#extracting just the values from eList

from itertools import combinations
g=list(combinations(val, 2))
#pairing up two teams values
def expected_result(rating1, rating2):
    exp = (rating2 - rating1)/400.
    Ea = 1/(1 + math.pow(10, exp))
    Eb = 1/(1 + math.pow(10, -exp))
    return Ea*100, Eb*100

for i in g:
    print(expected_result(*i))
    #unpacking each tuple into function
```

first of we need to make pairs of each team without repetition  once we have list of tuples we can unpack using `for` loop
Output:

```
(54.592192278048365, 45.407807721951635)
(59.52430396515719, 40.47569603484281)
(65.32171672188699, 34.67828327811303)
(69.36879164219654, 30.63120835780346)
(69.36879164219654, 30.63120835780346)......
```